# Initializing weights that are a pointwise product of multiple variables

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, word2vec, weight-initialization, fasttext

In two-layer perceptrons that slide across words of text, such as [word2vec](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5021-distributed-representations-of-words-and-phrases-and-their-compositionality.pdf) and [fastText](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.04606.pdf), hidden layer heights may be a product of two random variables such as positional embeddings and word embeddings [(Mikolov et al. 2017, Section 2.2)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.09405.pdf#page=2): $$v_c = \sum_{p\in P} d_p \odot u_{t+p}$$ However, it's unclear to me how to best initialize the two variables.

When only word embeddings are used for the hidden layer weights, word2vec and fastText initialize them to $\mathcal{U}(-1 / \text{fan_out}; 1 / \text{fan_out})$. When the product of two random variables is used, we might:

- initialize the first variable with ones and the other variable with $\mathcal{U}(-1 / \text{fan_out}; 1 / \text{fan_out})$: This would maintain the distribution of the weights, but the gradients to the second variable would be way too large.
- initialize the variables with [a 2-factor of $\mathcal{U}(0, 1)$](http://ravshansk.com/articles/uniform-distribution.html):

  [image: 2-factor of the uniform random distribution]

  and then rescale their product to $[-1 / \text{fan_out}; 1 / \text{fan_out}]$. This would maintain the distribution of the weights, but enlarge the gradients to both variables, since they are now both initialized to ones or close to ones.

I will appreciate any ideas and pointers to existing research in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

The most useful ways to initialize embedding model weights is either random or with pre-existing weights. If random weight initialization is chosen, the samples should be between 0 and 1.